# Как в xaml создать объект с пользовательским типом данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Речь идет не об элементе управления. Например, чтобы мне создать `string`, я должен написать так

`<sys:String x:Key="str">my string</sys:String>`

где sys - требуемое пространство имен.

А как должен выглядеть класс `MyClass`, чтобы я мог объявить его в xaml так же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой класс должен иметь пустой конструктор - он будет вызываться парсером, и не быть вложенным в другой класс.

Всё, дальше можно добавлять ссылку в xaml, используя конструкцию xmlns:

```
xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop"
```

В объявлении нужно указать namespace и сборку, откуда загружать тип. Если тип находится в той же сборке, где используется, директиву assembly можно опустить, если мне память не изменяет.

Подробнее на MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753379(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: И скачай уже книгу по WPF :)

Comment: книга по программированию - одна из самых бесполезных для меня вещей. Найти ответы на мои вопросы по оглавлению чаще всего невозможно

Comment: Статью я эту нашел перед тем как задать вопрос. Она не помогла создать в xaml экземпляр моего класса как `<local:MyClass x:Key="str">my string</local:MyClass>`

Comment: книга по программированию гораздо лучше, чем ответы от незнакомцев в интернете. Она поможет структурировать знания в голове. А так ты просто по верхам хватаешь, в надежде быстро всё понять. Так не получится, это тебе не грузчиком работать.

Comment: Что касается твоего класса, читай статью внимательно. В ней есть абсолютно все ответы.

Comment: Нет, я не нашел там `ContentPropertyAttribute`, например. Не нашел TypeConverter. Там очень общие и абстрактные сведения

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753379%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#XAMLCONtent а это что тогда?